# Does Anyone Know The Episode of Star Trek Where the Replicator is Used to Recycle a Book?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, episode-identification, replicator

Does anyone know the episode of Star Trek: Voyager where Captain Janeway placed a book in the replicator and had it recycled? I am looking for the screencap when the book disappeared off the replicator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**Episode 6x11: Fair Haven**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Fair_Haven_(episode))

In this episode, "Fair Haven" is introduced as one of Paris' new holodeck creations. Captain Janeway eventually falls in love with one of the created residents, who's interest in poetry leads Captain Janeway to read a series of books on Irish literature. Later in the episode, Captain Janeway can be seen recycling the literature in her quarters.

---

The recycling is mentioned in the original transcript of the episode:

> **[Janeway's quarters]**
>
> (Janeway picks up a pile of books, presumably Irish 19th century poetry, and takes them to the replicator.)
>
> JANEWAY: Computer, recycle.
>
> [*- transcript of Star Trek Voyager Episode 611 - "Safe Haven"*](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/610.htm)

---

This image shows Captain Janeway, moments before recycling the books:

[image: An image of Captain Janeway, moments before recycling the books, in "Safe Haven".]

---

I found this episode by googling "star trek recycling books", and clicking on the first link.

Comment: I have not yet found an image of said book recycling, but since I have access to this series on Netflix, I will take a picture to upload when I get home.

Comment: Nice find regardless!

Comment: Thanks, this is the image I was looking for. TrekCore has an excellent selection of screencaps all you need to know is where to look.
http://voy.trekcore.com/gallery/albums/6x11/PDVD_169.jpg

Comment: Marie Kondo is just off-screen reminding the captain to thank the books before letting them go with confidence.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was [Year of Hell](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0709014/). Recycling is required because Voyager has run afoul of the Krenim, a species that are extremely powerful and can manipulate time. Voyager in unable to contend with the Krenim weapons and resources are in even shorter supply than usual, hence the recycling.

Comment: I initially thought it was this episode, but revisiting it, I was mistaken between the book and a pocket watch that was given to Jane.

Comment: Yes, I remember the watch, but to be honest I haven't finished the series yet, so I guess the book comes later